# Tappable items within recyclerview with OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

*inception sounds*

It might not be the best idea, but here's a 4 second gif of what I'm trying to do and the problem I've run into.

https://i.imgur.com/Z3iAyNc.gifv (sorry, embedding wasn't allowed).

I have a `RecyclerView` with in each item a `LinearLayout` with category details and a hidden `LinearLayout` with another `recyclerView`. The idea is you see the categories, and once you tap on it, it expands to show the relevant posts. Another tap on the category should open the category detail page and a tap on a post should open the relevant post detail page.

I have it working, but as you can see in the gif, I have to tap at least two times, even though I never wrote it like that. It's the same for the LinearLayout's `onClickListener` It's like the parent `RecyclerView` hijacks the first tap.

Here's a schematic rundown of my code

```
    adapter.setOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemListener.RecyclerTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {
            final LinearLayout postView = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.profileCheckinDetailsView);
            // The IF statement prevents reloading the view when it is already open.
            if (postView.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                RelativeLayout itemView = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
[... etc]
```

And beneath it there's another `setOnItemTouchListener` for the child `RecyclerView`.

Am I doing this right, and if so, how to make sure both items register the first tap as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the rest of your click listener? Also, you might want to rethink setting a click listener inside of another click listener.

Comment: I'm here to rethink exactly that. I'm just looking for a *why not* and which way would be better. The rest of the code doesn't do anything other than open a new activity. I just pasted my sample here to show I didn't accidentally make it a OnItemDoubleTouchListener or something. I feel like my case isn't so unconventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The layout]

Sometimes typing out a question helps you think differently. I removed the top recyclerview's touch listener and replaced the item layout with this. Both layouts get their own onClickListener. With `((LinearLayout)v.getParent())` I managed to have them control eachother.

Much easier and more effective I believe.